# Do I need to sanitize $_POST['keyword'] before send to 's' parameter?

Tags: sql, sanitization

Anyone know how to sanitize the $_POST for wordpress?

```
$args = array(
   's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ),
);
```

Comment: If you're performing a search generally `POST` would be the incorrect request method. `GET` is ore appropriate.

Comment: But I send the 'keyword' value by using ajax post method.

Comment: You should be using GET.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below WordPress function to sanitize the value:

```
sanitize_text_field( $_POST['keyword'] );
```

You can also check more detail here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/

Comment: Is it useful for SQL injection?

Answer (score 0):

You Use Default PHP FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING filter removes tags and remove or encode special characters from a string.

Possible options and flags:

- **FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES** - Do not encode quotes
- **FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW** - Remove characters with ASCII value < 32
- **FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH** - Remove characters with ASCII value > 127
- **FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW** - Encode characters with ASCII value < 32
- **FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH** - Encode characters with ASCII value > 127
- **FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP** - Encode the "&" character to &

> Usage this :

```
$filtervar = filter_var($_POST['keyword'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$args = array(
  's' => $filtervar
 );
```

Example :

```
<?php
$str = "<h1>Hello WorldÆØÅ!</h1>";
$newstr = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
echo $newstr;
?>
```

Output: Hello World!

Comment: But it accept '=' sign and special character in input data. I think special characters not allowed for input data